# How to check data from pivot table?

Tags: laravel

I have an `Event` and `User` model which have a pivot table called `event_users`.
In the pivot table `event_id` and `user_id` is saved when user press participate button.

I have displayed all the event list. 
Now i want to display event which is participated as participated and not participated as participate.

i have tried
**controller**

```
public function vieweventlist()
{
    $data['events'] = Event::with('users')->get();

    return view('page',$data);
}
```

**blade file**

```
@foreach($events as $event)
    <h1>Event Name</h1>
    @foreach($event->users as $check)
        @if($check->pivot->user_id == auth()->user()->id && $check->pivot->event_id == $event->id)
            <button type="button" class="btn participateevent" disabled>Participated</button>
        @else
            <button type="button" class="btn participateevent">Participate</button>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I have set `belongsToMany` relation in both the `Event` and `User` models.

The problem with this code is second foreach loop is pivot table loop. Suppose I have one data in pivot table. I have list down 5 events. Because of pivot table foreach (Second one) only one button is shown in blade file which is participated but doesn't show @else participate button.

Comment: Are you wanting to show if the currently logged in user has participated in the event or are you wanting to show if the event has participants?

Comment: Did the answer below help fix your issue ?

Comment: If the answer worked for you, mark as "the answer" to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your second foreach makes it so only events who has participants (ether the logged in user or not) will show a button (participated or participate). If an event has no users attached to it, no button will be shown.

If you want to get the list of events with the information "if the current user is already participating to it or not" then here is a better way.

**Controller**

```php
public function vieweventlist(){
    $data['events'] = Event::withCount('users', function($user) {
        $user->where('id','=', auth()->id());
    })->get();
 return view('page',$data);
}
```

**Blade**

```html
@foreach($events as $event)
    <h1>Event Name</h1>
    @if($event->users_count)
      <button type="button" class="btn participateevent" disabled>Participated</button>
    @else 
      <button type="button" class="btn participateevent">Participate</button>
    @endif
@endforeach
```